# Can't locate git-cvsimport?

Tags: git

Is `git-cvsimport` part of the standard Git installation? I have two servers with Git versions 1.7.3.1 and 1.7.4, but none of them seem to have `git-cvsimport`. Is it part of a later version?

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command is "git cvsimport". It's a subcommand of git, not a separate binary/shell script (and it should be part of the standard installation, if you compile it yourself. Ubuntu or other linux packages might have a separate package for that).

Comment: Thanks. It worked, but the v1.7.3 installation says `git: 'cvsimport' is not a git command. See 'git --help'`. Was this available in previous versions? It might be something to do with the installation. (I'm working on a SUSE Linux platform)

Answer (score 46):

For ubuntu natty:

```
sudo apt-get install git-cvs
```

Answer (score 6):

On Fedora, it's not installed by default, so: "sudo yum install git-cvs".